# Mongo db and using maps in queries

Tags: json, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

Im new to mongo and am trygin to figure out queries, im using java driver

I have a document in the database which is as follows

```
{"name":"joe", "surname":"bloggs", "other": {"name":"fred", "surname"    :   "flint"}, "important" : "important info that does not chnage" }
```

Now i want to do a upsert on the document and only update it if it does not exist

I have the following which i wan tto insert if it doesnt exist and update if it does.

```
        Bson filter = Filters.and(
                Filters.eq("name", oldObj.getName()),
                Filters.eq("surname", oldObj.getSurname()),
                Filters.eq("translations", oldObj.getOtherMap())
        );



    Document documentToInsertUpdate = new Document();
    documentToInsertUpdate.put("important", newObj.getInfo());
    documentToInsertUpdate.put("name", newObj.getName());
    documentToInsertUpdate.put("surname", newObj.getSurname());
    documentToInsertUpdate.put("other", newObj.getOtherMap());

    Bson update = new Document("$set", documentToInsertUpdate);
    UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);

collection.updateOne(filter, update, options,   getSingleResultCallback(new ArrayList<Translations>()));
```

there seems to be a problem when i try to set the "other" section of the json in the filter and the document, it doesnt work. If i remove the "other" sections from the filter and documentToInsertUpdate it works fine.

How can i work with the second part i.e

```
"other": {"name":"fred", "surname" : "flint"}
```

Comment: do you get any error when you have the `other` ?

Comment: @SagarReddy i get the following:  org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.util.HashMap